# Java Method Implementation

Tags: java, methods

I'm required to implement methods into a simple program to familiarize myself with them in Java.

My code so far is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab5a
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double[] a = {1, 0, 0};
        double[] b = {0, 1, 1};
        double[] c = {1, 1, 1};
        double[] d = {0, 0, 1};

        double ab = Math.sqrt (
                (a[0]-b[0])*(a[0]-b[0]) +
                (a[1]-b[1])*(a[1]-b[1]) +
                (a[2]-b[2])*(a[2]-b[2]) );

        double ac = Math.sqrt (
                (a[0]-c[0])*(a[0]-c[0]) +
                (a[1]-c[1])*(a[1]-c[1]) +
                (a[2]-c[2])*(a[2]-c[2]) );

        double ad = Math.sqrt (
                (a[0]-d[0])*(a[0]-d[0]) +
                (a[1]-d[1])*(a[1]-d[1]) +
                (a[2]-d[2])*(a[2]-d[2]) );

        System.out.println("ab=" + ab + ",  ac=" + ac + ",  ad=" + ad);     
    }
}
```

And my instructions are to:

```
Next, copy the class to Lab5b.java, and replace the individual distance calculations by calls to a single
public static method that computes the distance between two points passed in as parameters. Also, implement
the method. Your method should have a signature something like the following:

    public static double distance(double[] a, double[] b)
```

I am very much new to Java and am struggling to understand what exactly the statement means.

Comment: You should ask the person who gave you this assignment

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Your question is off-topic because it is not specific enough.  StackOverflow is not for discussions, tutorials or questions of the form "Here's my assignment, here's what I have so far, please help".  If you can identify a particular issue you are having and write a specific question, that would be on-topic.

Comment: @TheLostMind Yes let me email my professor at midnight when I am trying to get ahead on my work, wait till tomorrow for his reply, and then get back to the program at a later time. Or maybe I can use the internet as a forum and find out what the assignment is asking, finish the program, and be on my way.

Comment: @snitchyc - *let me email my professor at midnight when I am trying to get ahead on my work, wait till tomorrow for his reply, and then get back to the program at a later time* -  Yes. That should be the right approach. Use SO only when you have specific questions not when you have to ask - *I don't know what my teacher wants* :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code should be this to define and call the new method with different parameters.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab5b {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double[] a = { 1, 0, 0 };
        double[] b = { 0, 1, 1 };
        double[] c = { 1, 1, 1 };
        double[] d = { 0, 0, 1 };

        // Call the method
        System.out.println("ab=" + distance(a, b) + ",  ac=" + distance(a, c) + ",  ad=" + distance(a, d));
    }

    // Define method
    public static double distance(double[] a, double[] b) {
        double dist = 0;
        dist = Math.sqrt (
                (a[0]-b[0])*(a[0]-b[0]) +
                (a[1]-b[1])*(a[1]-b[1]) +
                (a[2]-b[2])*(a[2]-b[2]) );

        return dist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was confused on how to insert my vales without getting rid of redundant lines.

Comment: I am sure he learned a lot thanks to your help..